# After starting docker swarm with port 1376, cannot docker init nor docker leave

Tags: docker

I am following the Docker Get Started tutorial (https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/)

After starting two virtual machines, I attempted to `docker init swarm`. Unfortunately, I did not read closely enough and passed in port `2376` instead of `2377`.

Things did not go as expected (expectedly) when trying to attach a second vm as a node, and I attempted to use `docker swarm leave` to leave the swarm and start over. I got a weird message and it suggested I use --force. I did.

Now I cannot run `docker swarm init` with port 2377:

```
Error response from daemon: This node is already part of a swarm. Use "docker swarm leave" to leave this swarm and join another one.
```

Nor can I run `docker swarm leave`:

`Error response from daemon: This node is not part of a swarm`

I'm puzzled, surely I'm missing something obvious--any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I wound up just tearing everything down. I deleted my virtualbox VMs and used `docker-machine rm <vm>` to remove the docker instances.